# Heat kernel expansion for entanglement entropy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, singularities, entanglement-entropy

Can somebody please let me know where I can find a reference for calculating heat kernel coefficients on a manifold with conical singularities? I am trying to compute the entanglement entropy for gauge fields using the heat kernel and the conical deficit angle method. I wanted to know how can I express the terms (in the entanglement entropy) beyond the leading UV divergent one in terms of invariants constructed out of the extrinsic and intrinsic curvature of the entangling region.

Comment: Try this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3712), Chapter 5.7.2, page 21, there are also some references given at the end of the chapter.